# I have two usb bluetooth adapters one doesn't work (hci1) but seems to be the default. How do I disable it so I can use the other one (hci0)?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I am using Mint 17 Cinnamon. I have two usb bluetooth adapters one (built-in) doesn't work (hci1) but seems to be the default. How do I disable it so I can use the other one (hci0 a Dongle)?

rkill list

`3: hci1: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

using a program called bluetooth manager; I can pair my devices with hci0 but not hci1. But after paring they don’t work. If I go to the cinnamon bluetooth settings only hci1 is an option

```
lspci -nnk #only 1 shows up-the internal one
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel driver in use: wl

lsusb #internal and dongle show up
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
```

Comment: Edit to include `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your internal one can be made to work with firmware

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/9oujf7jzgy73z4m/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

But since the question is how to disable the internal

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules
```

Then enter the following

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0a5c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="21d7", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Save, exit gedit, and reboot, the internal card will not show in `rfkill list all`

Comment: The firmware update didn't work. But removing it did make the dongle work. Thanks

Comment: The firmware usually works, unless you still have a 3.13 kernel, then you would need `sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd`  You can check kernel with `uname -a`

Comment: The link to the driver is broken. This one seems to work:
https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm